# Salary matrix month over month

Tags: sql

I have spent so much time on the following task and my final result is no elegant at all. I have two tables (Dec, Jan) with user_id and salary range `(0-5000, 5000-10000......)` I need to know the transfers of the users from one salary range to another.
table example dec:

| user_id | salary_range |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 0-5k |
| 125 | 10k-15k |
| 126 | 10k-20k |
| 202 | 0-5k |

table example jan:

| user_id | salary_range |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 0-5k |
| 125 | 15k-20k |
| 126 | 10k-20k |
| 999 | 5K-10k |

table example output:

| range | 0-5k | 5k-10k | 10k-15k | 15k-20k | left_clients | new_clients |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0-5k | 50% | 0 | 0 | 0 | 50% | 0 |
| 5k-10k | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 100% |
| 15k-20k | 0 | 0 | 0 | 100% | 0 | 0 |
| 20k-25k | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Hope I made it correct

```
SELECT '0-5K' AS RANGE,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_1 = nov.N_1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_A_C AS '0-5K'N, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_1 = nov.N_2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_A_C AS '5K-10K'N, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_1 = nov.N_3 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_A_C AS '10K-15K'N,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_1 = nov.N_4 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_A_C AS '15K-20K'N,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_1 = nov.N_5 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_A_C AS '20K-25K'N,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_1 = nov.N_6 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_A_C AS '25K-30K'N,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_1 = nov.N_7 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_A_C AS '30K-35K'N,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_1 = nov.N_8 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_A_C AS '35K-40K'N,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_1 = nov.N_9 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_A_C AS '40K-45K'N,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_1 = nov.N_10 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_A_C AS '45K-50K'N,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_1 = nov.N_11 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_A_C AS '50K-55K'N,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_1 = nov.N_12 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_A_C AS '55K-60K'N,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_1 = nov.N_13 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_A_C AS '60K-65K'N,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_1 = nov.N_14 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_A_C AS '65K-70K'N,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_1 = nov.N_15 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_A_C AS '70K-100K'N,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_1 = nov.N_16 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_A_C AS '100K-150K'N,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_1 = nov.N_17 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_A_C AS '150K-200K'N,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_1 = nov.N_18 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_A_C AS '200K-250K'N,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_1 = nov.N_19 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_A_C AS '+200'N,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_1 = 1 AND nov.N_1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_A_C AS LEAVING,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_1 IS NULL AND nov.N_1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_A_C AS new 
  FROM october_clients AS oct 
  FULL JOIN november_clients AS nov 
  ON oct.user_id = nov.user_id 
  UNION SELECT '5-10K' AS RANGE,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_2 = nov.N_1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_B_C AS '0-5K'N,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_2 = nov.N_2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_B_C AS '5K-10K'N,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_2 = nov.N_3 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_B_C AS '10K-15K'N,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_2 = nov.N_4 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_B_C AS '15K-20K'N,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_2 = nov.N_5 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_B_C AS '20K-25K'N,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_2 = nov.N_6 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_B_C AS '25K-30K'N,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_2 = nov.N_7 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_B_C AS '30K-35K'N,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_2 = nov.N_8 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_B_C AS '35K-40K'N,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_2 = nov.N_9 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_B_C AS '40K-45K'N,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_2 = nov.N_10 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_B_C AS '45K-50K'N,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_2 = nov.N_11 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_B_C AS '50K-55K'N,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_2 = nov.N_12 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_B_C AS '55K-60K'N,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_2 = nov.N_13 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_B_C AS '60K-65K'N,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_2 = nov.N_14 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_B_C AS '65K-70K'N,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_2 = nov.N_15 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_B_C AS '70K-100K'N,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_2 = nov.N_16 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_B_C AS '100K-150K'N,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_2 = nov.N_17 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_B_C AS '150K-200K'N,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_2 = nov.N_18 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_B_C AS '200K-250K'N,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_2 = nov.N_19 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_B_C AS '+200'N,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_2 = 1 AND nov.N_2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_B_C AS LEAVING,
  SUM(CASE WHEN oct.N_2 IS NULL AND nov.N_2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / &USERS_A_C AS new 
  FROM october_clients AS oct 
  FULL JOIN november_clients AS nov 
  ON oct.user_id = nov.user_id;
```

Comment: Please update your question with the definitions/DDL of the tables involved, some sample data for those tables and the result you want to achieve, based on that sample data. Please use editable text for all of this - don't post images

Comment: Hi I added an example data

Answer (score 0):

**ORACLE**  (we don't know your RDBMS)
Your sample data  had to be changed a bit 'cause they don't match your expected result.

```sql
WITH
    t1_ranges (USER_ID, SALARY_RANGE) AS
      (
          Select 123,       '0-5K' From Dual Union All
          Select 125,       '10K-15K' From Dual Union All
          Select 126,       '15K-20K' From Dual Union All
          Select 202,       '0-5K' From Dual 
      ),
    t2_ranges (USER_ID, SALARY_RANGE) AS
      (
          Select 123,       '0-5K' From Dual Union All
          Select 125,       '15K-20K' From Dual Union All
          Select 126,       '10K-15K' From Dual Union All
          Select 999,       '5K-10K' From Dual 
      ),
```

Create cte holding the ranges of interest and another one (I named it grid) that will give you an insight in salary changes between two tables (months):

```sql
  ranges (ID, SALARY_RANGE) AS
      (
          Select 1, '0-5K'    From Dual Union All
          Select 2, '5K-10K'  From Dual Union All
          Select 3, '10K-15K' From Dual Union All
          Select 4, '15K-20K' From Dual 
      ),
  grid AS
      (  Select    r.ID, r.SALARY_RANGE, 
                      CASE 
                            CASE WHEN t1.USER_ID Is Not Null And t1.USER_ID In(SELECT USER_ID From t2_ranges) THEN 'BOTH' 
                                 WHEN t1.USER_ID Is Not Null And t1.USER_ID Not In(SELECT USER_ID From t2_ranges) THEN 'LEFT'
                                 WHEN t2.USER_ID Is Not Null And t2.USER_ID Not In(SELECT USER_ID From t1_ranges) THEN 'NEW'
                            END 
                                WHEN 'LEFT' THEN t1.USER_ID
                                WHEN 'NEW' THEN t2.USER_ID
                      ELSE t1.USER_ID
                      END "USER_ID",
                      --
                      CASE WHEN t1.USER_ID Is Not Null And t1.USER_ID In(SELECT USER_ID From t2_ranges) 
                              THEN (Select SALARY_RANGE From t1_ranges Where USER_ID = t1.USER_ID) || '/' || (Select SALARY_RANGE From t2_ranges Where USER_ID = t1.USER_ID)  
                           WHEN t1.USER_ID Is Not Null And t1.USER_ID Not In(SELECT USER_ID From t2_ranges) 
                              THEN t1.SALARY_RANGE || '/NONE'             --left
                           WHEN t2.USER_ID Is Not Null And t2.USER_ID Not In(SELECT USER_ID From t1_ranges) 
                              THEN 'NONE/' || t2.SALARY_RANGE             --new
                      END "SR1_SR2"
          From        ranges r
          Left Join   t1_ranges t1 ON(t1.SALARY_RANGE = r.SALARY_RANGE)
          Left Join   t2_ranges t2 ON(t2.SALARY_RANGE = r.SALARY_RANGE)
          Where       COALESCE(t1.USER_ID, t2.USER_ID) Is Not Null
          Order By    r.ID
      )
```

From grid's resulting dataset...

```sql
        ID SALARY_RANGE    USER_ID SR1_SR2       
---------- ------------ ---------- ---------------
         1 0-5K                202 0-5K/NONE       
         1 0-5K                123 0-5K/0-5K       
         2 5K-10K              999 NONE/5K-10K     
         3 10K-15K             125 10K-15K/15K-20K 
         4 15K-20K             126 15K-20K/10K-15K
```

... you could see what was happening with users salaries between theese two months. Out of this you could extract the changes per user. To get your matrix with percentages you could use CASE expressions with analytic functions to prepare data for pivoting and aggregation so you could get your expected output. Here is the main SQL:

```sql
SELECT    SALARY_RANGE, Max(Nvl(SR_0_5K, 0)) "0-5K", Max(Nvl(SR_5K_10K, 0)) "5K-10K", Max(Nvl(SR_10K_15K, 0)) "10K-15K2", Max(Nvl(SR_15K_20K, 0)) "15K-20K", 
          MAX(PCT_LEFT) "LEFT_CLIENTS", MAX(PCT_NEW) "NEW_CLIENTS"

FROM (  SELECT  ID, SALARY_RANGE, USER_ID, 
                CASE WHEN CNT_1 > 0 And SubStr(SR1_SR2, 1, InStr(SR1_SR2, '/') - 1) = SubStr(SR1_SR2, InStr(SR1_SR2, '/') + 1) 
                        THEN CNT_2*100/CNT_1 
                     WHEN CNT_1 > 0 And SubStr(SR1_SR2, 1, InStr(SR1_SR2, '/') - 1) != SubStr(SR1_SR2, InStr(SR1_SR2, '/') + 1) And InStr(SR1_SR2, 'NONE') = 0
                        THEN (CNT_1 - CNT_2)*100/CNT_1
                ELSE 0 END "PCT_SR",
                --
                CASE WHEN LEFT_CL > 0 And CNT_1 > 0 THEN LEFT_CL*100/CNT_1 ELSE 0 END "PCT_LEFT",
                CASE WHEN NEW_CL > 0 And CNT_2 > 0 THEN NEW_CL*100/CNT_2 ELSE 0 END "PCT_NEW"
        FROM    (Select  ID, SALARY_RANGE, USER_ID, SR1_SR2,
                         Sum(CASE WHEN InStr(SR1_SR2, SALARY_RANGE) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(Partition By SALARY_RANGE) "CNT_1",
                         Sum(CASE WHEN InStr(SubStr(SR1_SR2, InStr(SR1_SR2, '/') + 1), SALARY_RANGE) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(Partition By SALARY_RANGE) "CNT_2",
                         CASE WHEN SubStr(SR1_SR2, InStr(SR1_SR2, '/')) = '/NONE' THEN
                              Sum(CASE WHEN InStr(SubStr(SR1_SR2, InStr(SR1_SR2, '/')), '/NONE') = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(Partition By SALARY_RANGE) 
                          ELSE 0 
                          END "LEFT_CL",
                          CASE WHEN SubStr(SR1_SR2, 1, 5) = 'NONE/' THEN
                              Sum(CASE WHEN InStr(SR1_SR2, 'NONE') = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(Partition By SALARY_RANGE) 
                          ELSE 0
                          END "NEW_CL"
                  From    grid g  
                )
    )
    PIVOT (  Max(PCT_SR) For ID IN(1 "SR_0_5K", 2 "SR_5K_10K", 3 "SR_10K_15K", 4 "SR_15K_20K")    ) 
GROUP BY SALARY_RANGE
ORDER BY CASE SALARY_RANGE WHEN '0-5K' THEN 1 WHEN '5K-10K' THEN 2 WHEN '10K-15K' THEN 3 ELSE 4 END
```

... with above sample data it results with:

```sql
SALARY_RANGE       0-5K     5K-10K   10K-15K2    15K-20K LEFT_CLIENTS NEW_CLIENTS
------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ------------ -----------
0-5K                 50          0          0          0           50           0 
5K-10K                0          0          0          0            0         100 
10K-15K               0          0        100          0            0           0 
15K-20K               0          0          0        100            0           0
```